# ERROR while starting the Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring Boot and spring when i try to run the following code i am getting `NullPointerException`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class cardApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

private JourneyService journeyService;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(cardApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scan.next();
    Double balance = scan.nextDouble();
    Card card = new Card(name, balance);

     // Travel begins


    Barrier checkIntoTube = new Barrier(card, Direction.IN, TravelMode.TUBE, Stations.Holborn);
    Barrier checkOutTube = new Barrier(card, Direction.OUT, TravelMode.TUBE, Stations.EarlsCourt);
    journeyService.startTubeJourney(checkIntoTube);

    journeyService.endTubeJourney(checkOutTube);

}
```

}

And My Exception trace looks like

```
2018-03-10 11:14:44.016  INFO 20240 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-10 11:14:44.039 ERROR 20240 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:793) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.alefedu.oyestercard.travel.OystercardApplication.main(OystercardApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.alefedu.oyestercard.travel.OystercardApplication.run(OystercardApplication.java:34) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:790) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2018-03-10 11:14:44.043  INFO 20240 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5599596c: startup date [Sat Mar 10 11:14:27 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-10 11:14:44.050  INFO 20240 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:793)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
    at com.alefedu.oyestercard.travel.OystercardApplication.main(OystercardApplication.java:17)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.alefedu.oyestercard.travel.OystercardApplication.run(OystercardApplication.java:34)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:790)
    ... 11 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I do not understand where i am doing wrong.

Comment: You have not autowired service.

Comment: Still not working after autowired.

Comment: First try writing without any code inside run method

Comment: Are you sure you have pasted correct code? Because in the stacktrace, class name is `OystercardApplication` and in the code class name is `cardApplication`

Comment: Yes, I just changed the app name while writing here.
@SanjayPatel it was working with code inside run method except when i call my journeyService method

Comment: May be that service having issue during bind.

Comment: Its a general service interface which in turn  calls the DAOs.

Comment: Your JourneyService must be a Spring bean to be injectable. Try to add the `@Service` annotation to the JourneyService class and use `@Autowire` to inject it into your OystercardApplication class

Comment: @ComponentScan is sloved my problem by including all packages

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I have autowired the class which I have invoked. It worked for me.

```
@Autowired
private JourneyService journeyService;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for something to be injected by Springs IoC container it must be defined as a bean or be an internal Spring object such as `ApplicationContext`.

So, define a new XML configuration file or use Java configuration to define the service as a bean and then inject it with `@Autowired` or `@Inject`.

Please refer to the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans) for more details.